PHP opcache.file_cache setting for a multi-node web server setup
While looking at my PHP 7.4 settings on my Windows Server 2019 servers, I came across the opcache.file_cache setting in my php.ini file.
I run my Moodle site on a load-balanced multi-node server setup, with two Windows web servers running Moodle and PHP and a shared Netapp storage layer for Moodledata.
The PHPInfo() output shows the default "no value" for this opcache.file_cache setting, implying that it is not optimally setup.
php.ini shows that the setting is still disabled:
;opcache.file_cache=
So, I want to see what happens to performance on my site if I enable that setting. However, none of the sparse documentation that I can find for this setting explains it very well. Must it point to a local folder on each server node, like this:
opcache.file_cache = "/home/www/opcache" for Linux or
opcache.file_cache = "C:\PHP\opcache" for Windows?
Or should it point to a shared folder that is accessible to all the Moodle web server nodes, like in the Moodledata folder? Example:
opcache.file_cache = "\\moodledata\opcache"
What is the requirement for Moodle? A local path on each server or a network path shared by all the web server nodes?

My understanding of "opcache.file_cache" is that it only really matters if you disable in-memory caching, or you want your cache to survive process restarts. The default cache (for web) uses 128MB of memory. As for storage, you could share the cache, however you'd want to make sure that the latency of the cache read doesn't defeat the purpose. Personally, if I wanted to use the file cache, I think I'd just have it local to each server. The path should just be a folder that PHP can write to, but it probably shouldn't be your web root.
